# Swift 3: can't set optional Bool via reflection

Tags: swift, reflection, swift3

I have the following code from a playground:

```
class Result :NSObject {
    var success :Bool? = false
    var message :String? = ""
}

var result = Result()
print(result.message)
var value :Bool? = true
result.setValue(value, forKey: "success")
result.setValue("hello", forKey: "message")
print(result.message)
```

This code fails on the first `result.setValue` line with the message "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key success." If I make the property success non-optional then this code works fine. The property message works fine regardless of whether it's optional or not.

What's going on here? Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reflection in Swift. You are using Objective-C reflection.
Optional value types (`BOOL`, `Int` etc) are not supported in Objective-C.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a way around it? Do I have to use NSNumber, for example.

Comment: Leaving `NSObject`'s `setValue` aside, there _is_ reflection in Swift, at least for introspection of values, e.g. `Mirror(reflecting: result).children.forEach { print($0) }`.

Comment: @IanNewson `NSNumber` is certainly a valid solution.

Comment: @dfri It's true `Mirror` is there, even documented now. However, I don't really consider that a finished product. Not something I would dare to use in production code. _Mirrors are used by playgrounds and the debugger._ (quoting documentation).